# Link to different pages depending on archive or single product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I use woocommerce the storefront theme.
I want the click buttons link to different pages depending on the site they are placed:
On the single-product.php I placed a custom link

I did this with this code:

```
    function my_custom_add_to_cart_redirect( $url ) {
        $url = get_permalink( 68 ); // URL to redirect to (1 is the page ID here)
        return $url;
    }
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'my_custom_add_to_cart_redirect' );
```

My startpage / frontpage is a product-archive.php . The thumbnails link to the single product. But the buttons beneath the thumbnails not. They also link to the page defined in the code above. **But like the thumbnails the buttons should link to the related product.**

**I need an if condition which checks if the button is placed on an archive page. If so, the button should link to single product.**

I tried to figure this out with the code placed in the thumbnails (because they link to the single-product). But I can’t find this code-snipped. I am just starting with php, wordpress and woocommerce on API level. Thank you and cheers

Comment: Are you trying to disable the add to cart function from loop products and when the add to cart button will be clicked you want click action should not perform add to cart but should redirect to a single product page?

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_archive/